# R list function

Tags: list, r

I have a problem applying a function to list elements. I have a list called "mylist", which looks like:

```
[[1]]  station global
       1        2
       1        2
       1        2
       1       14
       1       38
       1      169

[[2]] station global
       2       2
       2       2
       2      23
       2      86
```

In each list, I need to set values of "global" less than or equal to 2 to NA.
I have used

``` dat.list <- lapply(mylist, ``[[``, 'global') ```
to get only the global data.

Defining af function:

```
fct <- function(x) {
x[x <= 2] <- NA
}
```

and writing
    `lapply(dat.list, fct)`
gives

```
[[1]] NA
[[2]] NA
```

What I would like to have is:

```
[[1]] station global
      1       NA
      1       NA
      1       NA
      1       14
      1       38
      1      169

[[2]] station global
      2       NA
      2       NA
      2       23
      2       86
```

I apprechiate any help or a point in the right direction, Regards Sisse

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted a reproducible example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for advice on how to do this.

x will take on the element of the list.  Since those appear to be data.frames, treat x as a data.frame:

```
fct <- function(x) {
   x$global[x$global <= 2] <- NA
   x
}
```